# Deploying Flask app using Dokku

Tags: flask, dokku

I have a Flask app deployed using dokku and now I want to modify the code and redeploy it. All the documents I found online says that I need to add git remote using below command

```
git remote add dokku dokku@mydomain.com:test
git push dokku master
```

Do i need to specify the domain.com:test as the domain name of my Flask application or it should be the git repo?

Comment: How did you deploy it in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to add remote as below and then push the changes.

```
git remote add dokku dokku@<IP of server where app is hosted>:<App Domain Name>
```

Then verify remote is added using git remote -v

```
git push dokku master -- to publish the change
```